# How can I upload a file when I ask a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I haven't found anyway to upload a text file when I am asking a question. How can I do so?

Answer (score 13):

You can't, and for a good reason too. Reduce your question to something that is of readable and digestible length and ask *that*. This is also called a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/).

If it's too long to copy and paste here, then that is an excellent indicator that it is too long. And before you ask, yes this applies to sample data too. Pare it down to just the part that is causing trouble *before* asking.

Comment: And if doing the work to prepare a SSCCE solves your problem, well then that's just an added bonus. *Man, writing a good question is hard!*